# Spring @Preauthorize not working properly when provided with hierachical roles?

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, hierarchy, roles

I have a Spring-based application which defines a hierarchical set of roles for its users, like the following :

```
    <bean id="roleHierarchy" class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_ROOT > ROLE_SUDOER
                ROLE_SUDOER > ROLE_USER
                ROLE_USER > ROLE_DUMB
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

so in my AccessDecisionManager, I am using 4 voters this way :

```
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
                    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

   <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="methodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
   </sec:global-method-security>
```

even though, I have configured this set of hierarchical roles, I am having an **ACCESS DENIED** exception when a user having the highest role, **ROLE_ROOT**, is trying to access the */myUrl* url in the following controller:

```
    @Controller
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUDOER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl")
    public class BuggyController extends AbstractController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public List<SensitiveItem> getSensitiveItems(final Principal principal)
        {
            // removed for brievety
        }
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace (a part of it actually):

```
10:55:16.012 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - [ ] - Authorization successful
10:55:16.012 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - [ ] - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.util.List com.xxxx.yyyy.BuggyController.getSensitiveItems(java.security.Principal); target is of class [com.xxxx.yyyy.BuggyController.getSensitiveItems]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasRole('ROLE_SUDOER')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8bc6b2e4: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@7a85da9c: Username: sudoer; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ROOT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.22.112; SessionId: 8CE7068F50AD373ED2194B76A188BCEF; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ROOT
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ROOT] one can reach [ROLE_ROOT, ROLE_SUDOER, ROLE_USER, ROLE_DUMB] in zero or more steps.
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@65685e97, returned: -1
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@29800e27, returned: 0
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@162137ba, returned: 0
10:55:16.015 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] WARN  c.d.d.utils.ExceptionResolver - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - catched an exception: Access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Logs clearly state that the **ROLE_ROOT** can **escalate down** to the **ROLE_SUDOER**:

```
10:55:16.013 [ajp-bio-8029-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl - [ 192.168.xx.yyy] - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ROOT] one can reach [ROLE_ROOT, ROLE_SUDOER, ROLE_USER, ROLE_DUMB] in zero or more steps.
```

**So my question is, if the ROLE_SUDOER is reachable from a higher priority role (here ROLE_ROOT), why is my call failing ?**

In order to get it running, I had to explicitly add the highest role ROLE_ROOT as part of the method security control expression :

```
    @Controller
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ROOT', 'ROLE_SUDOER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl")
    public class BuggyController extends AbstractController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public List<SensitiveItem> getSensitiveItems(final Principal principal)
        {
            // removed for brievety
        }
    }
```

Which is really stupid since, it can become quite complicated if your hierarchical role set is huge : and that's exactly what hierarchical roles are for. It allows efficient role security control so that higher-priority roles can include lower priority ones.

Can someone help me on this issue ? Thanks in advance.